# Is my activity constructive?

Tags: discussion

I ask a lot of hypothetical questions because I'm curious about the answers. However, the more I think about it, I'm not sure this is constructive activity, especially since it could draw attention away from more useful questions.

Would it be better if I stopped asking useless but interesting questions?

Answer (score 8):

### You have given us both Gold and Lead

Some of your hypotheticals I personally find really good and they are gold. You can see them yourself, your high-voted ones.

You also have given us a couple of hypotheticals that are either convoluted, ill-researched, or just badly worded and thus received little traction or votes down.

Just go on. Just please try to think through your hypotheticals and see if they are clear.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with asking hypothetical questions on law.se. Indeed there is an argument that to avoid asking for specific legal advice, **only** hypothetical questions should be asked. Many of the best questions here are purely hypothetical or purely theoretical. If people don't find your questions productive, they will ignore them or perhaps downvote them.